# Sibelius 7 score key sig changes

Tags: key, sibelius

I'm changing from F Minor to Major in a Sib 7 score. The machine just gives one flat for the new section, and I want three naturals and one sharp. How do I get it to do it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

F Minor has four flats in its key signature.
F Major has one flat.
You say want three naturals and one **sharp**.
Do you mean three naturals and one **flat**? (Hope so!)

By default Sibelius has Cautionary Naturals turned off:
[image]

And the stave looks like this:
[image]

With Cautionary Naturals turned on, the stave looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turn on 'Cautionary naturals' in Engraving Rules/Clefs and key signatures.

But maybe the information that, despite what we learned for our Grade 5 theory exams all those years ago, it is now acceptable to omit them will be sufficient?